# Haskell HXT parse condition

Tags: xml, haskell, hxt

i'm trying to parse this xml:

```
...
<member>
  <name>id</name>
  <value>
    <string>1</string>
  </value>
</member>
<member>
  <name>description</name>
  <value>
    <string>sdfsdfsdf</string>
  </value>
</member>
...
```

how to parse only the "<member>" tags with a subordinate "name"-tag = "id"?

i tried:

```
getroot = multi ( ( getChildren >>> hasName "name" >>> hasText "id") `guards` (isElem >>> hasName "member"  ) ) 

main = do
print <- runX (parseXML "test2.xml" >>> getroot >>> putXmlTree "-")
```

Comment: What was the error message or problem?

Comment: no error message.
but, no description-tag ("<member><name>description...") should be parsed.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the filter `hasName "name"`, you get the `<name>` tag. That node itself is not a text node, so `hasText "id"` fails. Here a modification that seems to work: (I also had to change the type of the argument of `hasText`, maybe a different version of HXT)

```
import Text.XML.HXT.Core

getroot = multi ( ( getChildren >>> hasName "name" >>> getChildren >>> hasText (=="id")) 
                   `guards` (isElem >>> hasName "member"  ) ) 

main = do
    runX (readDocument [] "test2.xml" >>> getroot >>> putXmlTree "-")
```

I’m not an expert of HXT so it might be that there is a much better way to do what you want.

Comment: You can write `getroot` a little more clearly as `multi $ isElem >>> hasName "member" </ (hasName "name" /> hasText (== "id"))`.